# Flutter sqflite list automatically updates on one screen but needs hot on another screen

Tags: flutter, crud, sqflite, flutter-futurebuilder

I have basically used the same code in two different screens to get a list of Todos from the database. In the first screen I have just retrieved and displayed all the Todos. In the second screen I have displayed a list that contains a particular substring entered by the user in the search bar of the first screen.

The UI updates itself in the second (Searching_Items) Screen if I update a Todo item there but when I go back the first (Todo_List) screen, I have to hot reload to show that same change.

First Screen

```
class TodoListWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const TodoListWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TodoListWidget> createState() => _TodoListWidgetState();
}

class _TodoListWidgetState extends State<TodoListWidget> {
  var doneOrNot = null;
  var iconChanger = Icons.check_box_outline_blank;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<List<Todo>>(
        future: TodoServiceHelper().getTodos(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Padding(
                  padding:
                      EdgeInsets.only(left: 7, top: 19, right: 7, bottom: 7),
                  child: ListTile(
                    onTap: () async {
                      await showDialog(
                        barrierDismissible: false,
                        context: context,
                        builder: ((context) {
                          return EditTodoDialogue(
                            title: snapshot.data![index].title.toString(),
                            desc: snapshot.data![index].description.toString(),
                            id: snapshot.data![index].id.toString(),
                            isDone: snapshot.data![index].isDone,
                          );
                        }),
                      );
                      setState(() {});
                    },
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    ),
                    dense: false,
                    visualDensity: VisualDensity(vertical: -3, horizontal: -3),
                    contentPadding:
                        EdgeInsets.only(left: 32, right: 32, top: 8, bottom: 8),
                    title: Text(
                      snapshot.data![index].title.toString(),
                      style: TextStyle(
                          decoration: doneOrNot,
                          color: Colors.black87,
                          fontSize: 30,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text(
                      snapshot.data![index].description.toString(),
                      style: TextStyle(
                          decoration: doneOrNot,
                          color: Colors.black45,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    leading: IconButton(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        icon: Icon(
                          !snapshot.data![index].isDone
                              ? iconChanger
                              : Icons.check_box,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          if (snapshot.data![index].isDone) {
                            Todo update = Todo(
                              title: snapshot.data![index].title.toString(),
                              description:
                                  snapshot.data![index].description.toString(),
                              id: snapshot.data![index].id.toString(),
                              isDone: snapshot.data![index].isDone,
                            );
                          } else {}
                        }),
                    trailing: IconButton(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.delete,
                          size: 30,
                          color: Color.fromARGB(198, 209, 40, 40),
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            TodoServiceHelper().deleteTodo(
                                snapshot.data![index].id.toString());
                          });
                        }),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text("Oops!");
          }
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Second Screen

```
class ShowingSerachedTitle extends StatefulWidget {
  String searchTerm;
  ShowingSerachedTitle({required this.searchTerm});

  @override
  State<ShowingSerachedTitle> createState() => _ShowingSerachedTitleState();
}

class _ShowingSerachedTitleState extends State<ShowingSerachedTitle> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<List<Todo>>(
        future: TodoServiceHelper().searchTerm(widget.searchTerm),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Column(children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 100,
              ),
              Flexible(
                child: Text(
                  'There are/isr ${snapshot.data!.length} with that search term',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50),
                ),
              ),
              Flexible(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding:
                        EdgeInsets.only(left: 7, top: 19, right: 7, bottom: 7),
                    child: ListTile(
                      onTap: () async {
                        await showDialog(
                          barrierDismissible: false,
                          context: context,
                          builder: ((context) {
                            return EditTodoDialogue(
                              title: snapshot.data![index].title.toString(),
                              desc:
                                  snapshot.data![index].description.toString(),
                              id: snapshot.data![index].id.toString(),
                              isDone: snapshot.data![index].isDone,
                            );
                          }),
                        );
                        setState(() {});
                        print('trying to update');
                      },
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      ),
                      dense: false,
                      visualDensity:
                          VisualDensity(vertical: -3, horizontal: -3),
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 32, right: 32, top: 8, bottom: 8),
                      title: Text(
                        snapshot.data![index].title.toString(),
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black87,
                            fontSize: 30,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      subtitle: Text(
                        snapshot.data![index].description.toString(),
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black45, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      trailing: IconButton(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.delete,
                            size: 30,
                            color: Color.fromARGB(198, 209, 40, 40),
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              TodoServiceHelper().deleteTodo(
                                  snapshot.data![index].id.toString());
                              print('trying to delete');
                            });
                          }),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ))
            ]);
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text("Oops!");
          }
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have used basically the same code in both the screens but the UI automatically updates in only the searching_Items screen

The functions used to update and delete Todo items:

Getting all the Todos

```
 Future getItemCount() async {
    final Database db = await initializeDB();
    final List<Map<String, Object?>> queryResult = await db.query('todos');
    var count = queryResult.length;
    print(count);

    return Future.value(count);
  }
```

Updating Todos

```
 Future<void> updateTodo(Todo todo) async {
    final Database db = await initializeDB();
    try {
      await db
          .update('todos', todo.toMap(), where: 'id= ?', whereArgs: [todo.id]);
    } catch (e) {
      print('$e');
    }
  }
```

Deleting Todos

```
 Future<void> deleteTodo(String? idd) async {
    final Database db = await initializeDB();

    try {
      await db.delete(
        'todos',
        where: 'id = ?',
        whereArgs: [idd],
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print('$e');
    }
  }
```

Filtering based on a substring provided by user

```
 Future<List<Todo>> searchTerm(String term) async {
    final Database db = await initializeDB();
    final List<Map<String, Object?>> result = await db.query(
      'todos',
      columns: ['title', 'description', 'id'],
      where: 'title || description LIKE ?',
      whereArgs: ['%$term%'],
    );
    List<Todo> filtered = [];
    for (var item in result) {
      filtered.add(Todo.fromMap(item));
    }

    return filtered;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you go back the first (Todo_List) screen. You need to "setState(() {});" like this for exemple

```
ElevatedButton(
                      child: const Text('Second Page'),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        await Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => ShowingSerachedTitle()),
                        );
                        setState(() {});
                      },
                    ),
```

I recommended you to use sqfentity

Comment: @mohitnx You need to wait until you come back from your second page before running setstate. Otherwise you run setstate too fast. Await and Async allow you to wait for the execution of a function.
https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await